# Getting All $_POST From Multiple Select Value

Tags: php, html, post

I have this HTML code :

```
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

and to make user able to select more than one items, I'm using this jQuery plugin : http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

but, once it submitted... the PHP script only able to retrieve one of `$_POST['cars']` value. the last one. how to make PHP to be able to retrieve ALL of it?

Comment: That's how selects work. unless you add the `multiple` attribute, only a single option is EVER submitted.

Comment: Supposing that jQuery *is* sending all the values, you still need to specify that `cars` is an array, by naming it `cars[]`.

Comment: @MarcB : you're right, I forgot to add <select name="cars" multiple="multiple">

Comment: @lserni : bro, how to put all selected value into array? you mean like this : <select name="cars[]" multiple="multiple"> ?

Comment: Exactly. (Then you'll have to walk the array).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've found the answer...

```
<select name="cars[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

and in the PHP part :

```
$cars = $_POST['cars'];
print_r ($cars);
```

Comment: Just to clarify. In HTML, you need to make sure the name attribute is an array, which you do by adding `[]` at the end of the name. As this example shows.

Comment: Just to clarify even more. This is a PHP trick that has nothing to do with the HTML/DOM spec.

Answer (score 0):

you must do the following:

//$_POST or $_GET is the method of your form request

```
foreach ($_POST['cars'] as $selected_option) {
    echo $selected_option;
}
```

that's it.

Comment: doesn't work for multiple values in the same select.

Comment: @AlexandruRada this when u recieve the data, but you have to do as the correect answer to send the data as multiple

Comment: try using php://input