# Get the selected value of a <select> tag in php

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to find out what is the value of the `<option>` in a `<select>` tag?

I have a form that contains a  tag, with several options. Then, I want to insert the selected value on the database.

Is this doable with PHP? Or do i need JS/Jquery?

EDIT: this is what i have tried:

This creates the variable and stores the value of the option.

```
$query=mysql_query("Select cargo from utilizadores where nome<>'admin'");
echo '<select name="icargo[]">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    foreach ($row as $cargo){
      echo '<option value="$cargo" name="icargo[]">'.$cargo.'</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

I send the variable this way, and then i try to receive it with a foreach:

```
$countcargo = 0;
foreach ($_POST["icargo"] as $cargoo){
  $cargoarray[$countcargo] = $cargo;
  $countcargo++;
}
```

Comment: Edited. Sorry i didn't day what i've already tried.

Comment: where do i add the multiple attribute?

Comment: `echo <select name="icargo[]" multiple>` If you want multiple.

Comment: take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110758/php-getting-all-post-from-html-multiple-select-value