# how to post multiple values in controller using single dropdown?

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, controller

Here is my code:

```
                            <div class="input-group" id="sector">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Sector</span>
                                <select class="form-control"  multiple>
                                    <? foreach ($sectors as $row): ?>
                                        <option value="<?= $row['sector']; ?>">
                                        <?= $row['sector']; ?></option>
                                    <? endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

I want to send the multiple selected value to controller.I have tried  but only last selected value is posted, not all. Can you please guide me??

Comment: Please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110758/php-getting-all-post-from-html-multiple-select-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a hidden field and as you select the drop down add the value to the hidden field with comma separation using javascript/jquery.
Finally when form is posted you can get the data with comma. You can use explode it by comma.

Comment: can u please elaborate with example??