# Get All Value Of Multiple Select And Display Automatically Without Choosing Value

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, multi-select

How can I get all value of the multiple-select  and display into the other page. I try to follow different answer from different stackoverflow questions that are related with my question but still they are almost the same giving me wrong output. But correct me if I wrong with that.

I try to analyze and  implement answer in the following link that has not display value.
1. [Getting All $_POST From Multiple Select Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110758/getting-all-post-from-multiple-select-value)
2. [How to get multiple selected values of select box in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php)
3. [How to get multiple selected values of select box in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php/2407401)
4. [Get all variables sent with POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207488/get-all-variables-sent-with-post)
5. [Using $_POST to get select option value from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139501/using-post-to-get-select-option-value-from-html)

How can I get the value from my select when I try to submit it using POST or GET? The following codes I  am using.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS File  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
  />
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="GET" action="display.php">
    <div class="row">     
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <select name="test" id="sbTwo" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
          <option value="Alpha">Alpha</option>
          <option value="Beta">Beta</option>
          <option value="Gamma">Gamma</option>
          <option value="Delta">Delta</option>
          <option value="Epsilon">Epsilon</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>    
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="2" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>

<style type="text/css">
  /* Button Primary */
  .btn-primary {
    color: #0275d8;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #0275d8;
  }

  .btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #0275d8;
    color: white;
    border-color: #0275d8;
  }
</style>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['test'])) {
 foreach ($_GET['test'] as $value){  
    echo $value."\n";
   }
}else{
    echo 'ERROR';
}
?>
```

Comment: change your select name to `name="test[]"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the name to `test[]` for multi select

```
 <select name="test[]" id="sbTwo" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Nothing happen, still I get the message 'ERROR'.

Comment: var_dump($_GET) and see what you're getting

Comment: @ArunKumaresh.I am getting  `array(1) { ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }`

Comment: Please help me and join in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150789/discussion-between-ailyn-and-farsay . @Arun Kumaresh

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in select box. in multiple select box you need to provide array name .  in your case it is test. but it should be test[]

2nd point - if you want to send data using form. you should use POST method because it is secure. so i have replaced GET with POST in your code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS File  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
  />
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="display.php">
    <div class="row">     
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <select name="test[]" id="sbTwo" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
          <option value="Alpha">Alpha</option>
          <option value="Beta">Beta</option>
          <option value="Gamma">Gamma</option>
          <option value="Delta">Delta</option>
          <option value="Epsilon">Epsilon</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>    
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="2" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>

<style type="text/css">
  /* Button Primary */
  .btn-primary {
    color: #0275d8;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #0275d8;
  }

  .btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #0275d8;
    color: white;
    border-color: #0275d8;
  }
</style>

and in you display.php  file code should be - 

<?php
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
 foreach ($_POST['test'] as $value){  
    echo $value."\n";
   }
}else{
    echo 'ERROR';
}
?>
```

Comment: Nothing happen, still I get the message 'ERROR'.

Comment: i just checked it again and it is working fine.  tell me where is your php code.  is it in the same page or in a different page 'display.php'

Comment: It is located on separate page, display.php

Comment: can you recheck your code ? is it same like i have posted at the bottom section of php code in my answer. if not replace again ... and also check html again is it same like i have posted in my answer...  like form method and select box name

Comment: It is located on separate page, display.php. I try also to use `var_dump($_GET)` to see what you're getting as a recommendation of Arun Kumaresh. Then I get `array(1) { ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150789/discussion-between-ailyn-and-farsay).

Comment: Please  help me and talk in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150789/discussion-between-ailyn-and-farsay